# How to display users in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay-6

How to get the list of all users of a liferay portal 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to fetch the list of all users.

`List<User> userList=userLocalServiceUtil.getUser(0,userLocalServiceUtil.getUserCount());`

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```java
List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(-1, -1);
```

In Velocity:

```html
<ul>
#set($userService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#foreach($user in $userService.getUsers(-1, -1))
    <li>$user.fullName</li>
#end
</ul>
```

For the Velocity one to work, you have to remove the restriction on `serviceLocator` by adding the following property to `portal-ext.properties`:

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```